# Limit tending to negative infinity proof

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I am new to proofs and would appreciate advice on this proof.

Prove that $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac1x = 0$.

Given $\epsilon>0$ find N such that:

if $x < N$ then $\left\lvert\frac1x - 0\right\rvert<\epsilon$

choose $N = -{1\over \epsilon}$.

Since ${x\to -\infty}$, $x < -{1 \over \epsilon}$, then $\left\lvert \frac1x - 0 \right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac1x \right\rvert = {1 \over -x} < \epsilon \Rightarrow x < -{1 \over \epsilon}$ qed.

Is this proof correct, and if not, where did I go wrong? Will also appreciate advice on the construction of the proof. Thank you.

Comment: I would just change the last line of your proof to "If $x<-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, then $\epsilon x<-1\Rightarrow \epsilon>-\frac{1}{x}\Rightarrow|\frac{1}{x}|=-\frac{1}{x}<\epsilon$".

Comment: @user84113 thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish, but I guess I didn't do it the right way. Are the other answers considered more valid ways of doing this proof?

Comment: As the two answers point out, you want to leave out  "$x\to -\infty$" at the beginning and the "$x<-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$" at the end; and your proof should show why $x<-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\Rightarrow |\frac{1}{x}|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder some things in your proof so that the wording is logical.

For example, instead of "Since $x \rightarrow -\infty$ ... ," something along the following lines would be more clear:

> Choose $N = -{1\over \epsilon}$.  Then $\forall x<N $,
>
> $\left\lvert \frac1x - 0 \right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac1x \right\rvert = {1 \over -x} < {1\over -N} = {1\over{1\over \epsilon}} = \epsilon$.

Comment: i suppose I was trying to show the reasoning behind why $x < -{1 \over \epsilon}$ but perhaps that isn't necessary. And if it isn't, what makes it not necessary?

Comment: The problem is, $x < -1/\epsilon$  isn't always true.  The way limits work is that once you've chosen the $N$, you can bound $|stuff|$ by $\epsilon$ when the variable of $|stuff|$ meets a certain requirement regarding $N$.  In your case, the variable is $x$, $|stuff|$ is $|1/x|$, and the requirement is "when $x < N$".  Also, all three of the responses you've received are perfectly valid.  We're expressing the same idea, but with our own styles.

Comment: I have thought a lot about these answers since yesterday and realized many things. I understand now that two ways of showing this proof works is to do as the comment user84413 left, which is essentially to solve for epsilon. Then there is this method, which I do not understand where the ${1 \over -N}$ comes from. It seems to come from the ${1 \over -x}$ on the LHS and then exchanging $x$ for $N$ which I understand, but how does it end up on the RHS to equal $\epsilon$?

Comment: You have to choose an $N$ such that $\forall x < N$ (according to your formulation of the limit here), $\left\lvert \frac1x - 0 \right\rvert < \epsilon$.  With this end in mind, the $-1\over x$ < $-1\over N$ comes from having assumed $x < N$.  I wrote my proof as a string of inequalities.  You can also break it up, step by step, and show that each pair of inequalities implies the next.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. I understand now how ${-1 \over x} < {-1 \over N}$ makes sense, thank you, the only thing left that i don't understand is how the ${1 \over -N}$ came into existence at all. I guess I don't see the relationship between it and anything else. Or in other words, it seems like ${1 \over -N}$ comes out of thin air to make the proof on the RHS equal $\epsilon$. What am I not understanding?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you're missing.  You chose $N = -{1\over\epsilon}$.  You also realized on your own that $|{1\over x}| = {1\over -x}$.  Once you let $x < N$, then ${1\over -x} < {1\over -N}$ follows almost immediately.

Comment: wow i feel like an idiot, thanks for letting me see that $x < N$ is easily turned into ${1 \over -x} < {1 \over -N}$. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: No problem.  Inequalities are the essence of analysis.  It's good that you've been so persistent in trying to understand all the little pieces.

Comment: It bothers me when I don't understand how something works :). I'm  teaching myself calculus so it helps to have a site like this where I can ask questions. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong expect the very last statement, in which $x<-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ appears both in the LHS and in the RHS.

You want to prove that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $x\leq N$ implies $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|\leq\varepsilon$.

Then you choose $N=-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ and check that such a choice works, since:

$$x\leq-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{|x|}\leq\varepsilon.$$